# Swizzle Tap Gesture Action in iOS Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, dynamic-library, swizzling, cocoa-touch

I am developing an Cocoa Touch Framework or a dynamic Library which would capture user actions using Swift.

E.g. When a user taps on a label, my framework should know about it.
For achieving this behaviour, I am using method swizzling.

I am creating an extension for the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.In this extension, in `initialize` method , I am swizzling the init :

```
open override class func initialize() {
    guard self === UITapGestureRecognizer.self else { return }

    let originalSelector = #selector(self.init(target:action:))
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(swizzled_init(target:action:))
    swizzling(self, originalSelector, swizzledSelector)
}

func swizzled_init(target: Any, action: Selector) {
    swizzled_init(target : target,action: action)
    print("swizzled_init"+action.description)

//This part is for swizzling the the action which is being provided by the developer at the time of init.

    guard self === UITapGestureRecognizer.self else { return }
    let originalSelector = action
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(swizzled_action(sender:))
    swizzling(self.classForCoder, originalSelector, swizzledSelector)
}

func swizzled_action(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil){
    print("swizzled_action"+(sender?.description)!)
}
```

After swizzling init, the instance of tap is nil in my ViewController.

```
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(sender:)))
```

And the second issue is this in the swizzled_init method:

```
guard self === UITapGestureRecognizer.self else { return }
```

which is getting failed.

Could you please direct me in resolving these issues?

Comment: Hi have you created this ?

Answer (score 2):

This was successful for me. I created an SDK capable of handling various class types, including my UIGestureRecognizer implementation.

```
import UIKit

extension UIGestureRecognizer {
static func swizzle() {
  if let originalMethod = 
   class_getInstanceMethod(UIGestureRecognizer.self, #selector(UIGestureRecognizer.init(target:action:))),
       let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIGestureRecognizer.self, #selector(UIGestureRecognizer.swizzled_init(target:action:))) {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
}

private static var _myComputedProperty = [String:Any]()

private var targetProperty:AnyObject? {
    get {
        let tmpAddress = String(format: "%ptargetProperty", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
        return UIGestureRecognizer._myComputedProperty[tmpAddress] as AnyObject
    }
    set(newValue) {
        let tmpAddress = String(format: "%ptargetProperty", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
        UIGestureRecognizer._myComputedProperty[tmpAddress] = newValue
    }
}

private var actionProperty:Selector? {
    get {
        let tmpAddress = String(format: "%pactionProperty", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
        return UIGestureRecognizer._myComputedProperty[tmpAddress] as? Selector
    }
    set(newValue) {
        let tmpAddress = String(format: "%pactionProperty", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
        UIGestureRecognizer._myComputedProperty[tmpAddress] = newValue
    }
}

@discardableResult @objc func swizzled_init(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector?) -> Selector {
    targetProperty = target
    actionProperty = action
    return swizzled_init(target: self, action:  #selector(swizzled_action))
}

@objc dynamic func swizzled_action() {
    guard let targetProperty = targetProperty, let actionProperty = actionProperty else { return }
    targetProperty.performSelector(onMainThread: actionProperty, with: self, waitUntilDone: false)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("trackEvent"), object: nil, userInfo: ["event": "interacted with on: \(self.description)"])
}
```

}

EDIT:

Please add TrackbleGesture since system gestures cannot be managed with this.

Any target that requires handling must extend TrackbleGesture.

```
import UIKit

 public protocol TrackbleGesture: AnyObject {}

 extension UIGestureRecognizer {
static func swizzle() {
    if let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIGestureRecognizer.self, #selector(UIGestureRecognizer.init(target:action:))),
       let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIGestureRecognizer.self, #selector(UIGestureRecognizer.swizzled_init(target:action:))) {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
}

private static var _myComputedProperty = [String:Any]()

private var targetProperty:AnyObject? {
    get {
        let tmpAddress = String(format: "%p-targetProperty", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
        return UIGestureRecognizer._myComputedProperty[tmpAddress] as AnyObject
    }
    set(newValue) {
        let tmpAddress = String(format: "%p-targetProperty", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
        UIGestureRecognizer._myComputedProperty[tmpAddress] = newValue
    }
}

private var actionProperty:Selector? {
    get {
        let tmpAddress = String(format: "%p-actionProperty", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
        return UIGestureRecognizer._myComputedProperty[tmpAddress] as? Selector
    }
    set(newValue) {
        let tmpAddress = String(format: "%p-actionProperty", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
        UIGestureRecognizer._myComputedProperty[tmpAddress] = newValue
    }
}

@discardableResult @objc func swizzled_init(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector?) -> Selector {
    guard target is TrackbleGesture else { return swizzled_init(target: target, action: action) }
    targetProperty = target
    actionProperty = action
    return swizzled_init(target: self, action:  #selector(swizzled_action))
}

@objc dynamic func swizzled_action() {
    guard let targetProperty = targetProperty, let actionProperty = actionProperty else { return }
    targetProperty.performSelector(onMainThread: actionProperty, with: self, waitUntilDone: false)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("trackEvent"), object: nil, userInfo: ["event": "interacted with: \(self.description)"])
}
```

}

to retain the correct state of the UIGestureRecognizer

change this line:

```
targetProperty.performSelector(onMainThread: actionProperty, with: self, waitUntilDone: false)
```

to:

```
targetProperty.performSelector(onMainThread: actionProperty, with: self, waitUntilDone: true)
```